# Business Objects - New 'InList' Variable (Help Needed)

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I'm using SAP BusinessObjects Web Intelligence 14.0.6, and am having trouble figuring out how to create a InList variable, that will replace multiple values  of one column, with replacement values I want it to display. I remember in old BO WebInel XI, there was a feature to keep adding a level to the variable. I don't see that in this version maybe

What I'm trying to do, is create a new variable called 'Region' that will replace certain values in a column called 'Site'. Example:

**SITE:** Hong Kong, Bangkok, Hanoi, California, Miami, Berlin, Paris

What I want is to have the variable called Region, replace these values with selected values in  Example:

**REGION:** AP, AP, AP, NA, NA, EU, EU

Its been years since I used BO, so I'm very rusty at this part. I know it can be done, cause I done it before, but this new version I'm a little clueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you want to use is:

```
=If [Site] InList('Hong Kong', 'Bangkok', 'Hanoi') Then 'AP'
ElseIf [Site] InList('California', 'Miami') Then 'NA'
ElseIf [Site] InList('Berlin', 'Paris') Then 'EU'
```

If `[Site]` contains a value different from the ones you mentioned, no value will be returned (`NULL`).

If you append the following to the formula:

```
Else 'Unknown'
```

... then `Unknown` will be shown if it the [Site]'s value isn't in the list.

If you want to find out more information regarding the formula's available, have a look at the manual [Using Functions, Formulas and Calculations in SAP BusinessObjects Web Intelligence 4.0 SP5](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir4/en/xi4sp5_ffc_en.pdf).

Comment: Please consider adopting @Praveen's answer or mirroring his adjustments.  The code you have has some syntax errors that prevent it from working on BusinessObjects Web Intelligence 4.x.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use InList and the above formula does not work. I changed the single quote to double quote and comma to semicolon ( as mentioned here https://bi.emea.nsn-net.net/BOE/portal/123/AnalyticalReporting/help/en/frameset.htm?471c17396e041014910aba7db0e91070.html)

```
=If [Site] InList("Hong Kong"; "Bangkok"; "Hanoi") Then "AP"
    ElseIf [Site] InList("California" ; "Miami") Then "NA"
    ElseIf [Site] InList("Berlin", "Paris") Then "EU"
```

Comment: Upvoted because you're correct, but next time please consider editing the accepted answer.  The linked documentation (p. 177) from the accepted answer matches yours, so it was likely a mistake.  The accepted answer explains `null` as well as the `Else` clause, making it better.